# How to make a YouTube iFrame Video Responsive

Tags: video, youtube, thumbnails, responsive

I have a YouTube video on my home page --> https://delicateseams.com/ half way down the page in the left content block.

The video thumbnail is not responsive on mobile devices.

Does anyone know how to get a YouTube video's thumbnail image to be responsive?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you could add a css section for mobile devices in your css: @media only screen and (max-device-width: SOMEWIDTH) {  //Your iframe size here, maybe 100%}

Comment: Exactly @AramBecker...it becomes a matter of what that css should look like. I tried `background-image:contain`, `width:100%`, `mx-width:100%` and nothing that I know of works.

Comment: I'm on my mobile right now I'll have a look at your page source as soon as I get to my PC

Comment: kay, sorry took longer than I thought to make some spare time. So from what I can gather your problem is that the iframe and it's parent have a fixed width (600px), but the flex layout around it allows it to be much smaller (On a small browser window both the "Stay in touch" panel and the video flow over their bounds. I'm looking into ways to fix this right now, the main problem is that the iframe looses it's ratio when removing the fixes width.

Comment: Thanks @AramBecker. I'll look at this over the next day or so...

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather your problem is that the iframe and it's parent have a fixed width (600px), but the flex layout around it allows it to be much smaller (On a small browser window both the "Stay in touch" panel and the video flow over their bounds.

Maybe this is something similar to your needs?

```css
.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.video-wrapper {
    min-width: 40%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:  10px 10px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .video-wrapper {
    min-width: 360px;
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.right-panel {
    width: 360px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.bordered {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.video-frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <iframe class="video-frame"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X_tYrnv_o6A?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
      <div class="bordered">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et elit feugiat, finibus orci a, ultricies velit. Proin ac cursus magna, nec dapibus orci. Cras aliquet magna vitae enim faucibus consequat. Morbi nisl lacus, porta nec imperdiet tempus, dictum vitae ligula. Etiam quis tincidunt lorem, quis viverra orci. Quisque scelerisque, odio sit amet congue laoreet, dui ipsum congue ligula, sed varius mi turpis ac velit. Integer id sem a nunc tincidunt scelerisque non ut magna. Duis in mauris ut eros finibus malesuada.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m1tLp64m/

I haven't tested it for responsive yet, but maybe the idea helps you. I presume you want your "Stay in touch" box a fixed width, at least that's how it looks in your webpage.

Hope this helps in any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this

```
       <div class="vid-container">
         <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/quPqtSl1hQE?rel=0=1" allowfullscreen id="busi-vid"></iframe>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .vid-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
.vid-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Courtesy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YffrCViTVk